# How to write simple test cases for testing a Login Api in android?

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit

I have been trying to write test cases for my APIS, all I have written so far is a `unit test cases` of a function email validation which is just for a sample.

What I actually want is stated as below -

I want to write an android test case for **Login API** that accepts `email` and `password.`

I have followed a lot of tutorials but every of link is saying to include a lot of dependencies like expresso,mockito etc.

So Isn't there any simpler process that I could integrate this directly into my pre-build Application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create test cases for a Login API (not a registration API), you only have to consider the possibility of your API returning success or failure. A user is either going to be providing a correct email and password, or an incorrect email and password and your api will respond accordingly.

To test, you could potentially create the following 4 test cases :

- Valid email, valid password
- Incorrect email, correct password (for the user associate to the password)
- Correct email, incorrect password
- Incorrect email, incorrect password.

Seeing as though you are not testing a registration API and you want to test the login api specifically as the question stated, there's no need to test whether or not the user enters valid data for email or password according to business logic.

As a brief example, you could do something like this :

```
@Test
public void testExampleWithCorrectValues() {
    String validEmail = "email";
    String validPassword = "password";

    boolean responseOfExecutingYourApiWithCorrectValues = how you get a response from the api

    Assert.assertEquals(true, responseOfExecutingYourApiWithCorrectValues);

}

@Test
public void testExampleWithIncorrectEmail() {
    String invalidEmail = "email1";
    String validPassword = "password";

    boolean responseOfExecutingYourApiWithIncorrectValues = how you get a response from the api

    Assert.assertEquals(false, responseOfExecutingYourApiWithIncorrectValues);

}


@Test
public void testExampleWithIncorrectPassword() {
    String validEmail = "email";
    String invalidPassword = "password1";

    boolean responseOfExecutingYourApiWithCorrectValues = how you get a response from the api

    Assert.assertEquals(false, responseOfExecutingYourApiWithCorrectValues);

}

@Test
public void testExampleWithIncorrectValues() {
    String invalidEmail = "email1";
    String invalidPassword = "password1";

    boolean responseOfExecutingYourApiWithIncorrectValues = how you get a response from the api
    Assert.assertEquals(false, responseOfExecutingYourApiWithIncorrectValues);
}
```

However, you have to note that your tests will then be hitting your actual API (making a service call) just to be ran and this is bad practice, that is why people tell you to use mockito and other frameworks to mock out your api call or responses